# HTML and CSS <nav> links positioning - BOOTSTRAP 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i need help with positioning my nav bar links. I will include my code so please tell me where i am wrong. Using Bootstrap for grid.
Problem is that my nav bar is not full width inside that div, even when set margins to 0 , when i set width 100% its stacked vertical.
`

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1>Web Engineering</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <nav class="nav">
                <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
                <a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
                <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

Didnt include any CSS bcs non of my CSS code is working what i want to do.
TASK: Float right my links and center them in middle of a DIV while my logo float left.

Comment: Your HTML structure is wrong for start.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a website where people code for you. This is easily found on google. Just search a bit harder :)

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 What is wrong with the OP's HTML structure, other than the misleading indentation?

Comment: Well i dont want anyone code for me, just need bootstrap sokution for this particular problem, but nvm i made my class for nav so its working now, just wanted to know workaround for bootstrap . @zvezdas1989 A kako je pravilan pocetak , jedni kazu ovako treba, da sve bude po row tagovima za svaki red

Comment: @Roy whell there isn't solution in documentation, i read it all.

Comment: @MrLister Well that's not how make it using bootstrap navbar classes etc. If  he wants to do it without the power the bootstrap that's fine of course, but then this question doesn't have anything to do with bootstrap navbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can do quick fix  with css  on

`.nav > a { 
float: left;
margin-rigth: 10px; 
}`

and on end clear both

```
.clear-div {
 clear: both;
}
```

Comment: about postition try  mt-auto  or ml-auto

Comment: thanks a lot m8. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example of bootstrap 4 beta navbar with proper structure:

```
<div id="myNav" class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-faded">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">One <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Two</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Three</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

You can view it live here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RjQoqB

Answer (score 1):

Using Flex

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row">
     <div class="p-6"><h1>Web Engineering</h1></div>
     <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
       <div class="p-2"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></div>
       <div class="p-2"><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></div>
       <div class="p-2"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></div>
     </div>
  </div>
   </body>
```